# Re-use the scriban template

Tags: sxa, sxa-storefront, scriban

Is there a way we can reuse a scriban template? I have a PromoBlock scriban template and I need to re-use that in the PromoHero and apply the Css Class to make it behave differently

This is the structure

[image: Scriban template]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 2 options.

1. Duplicate the scriban template into the `Hero` variant and just add the class to the variant.
2. Just have one variant and use an optional Style class tick to add the CSS class that changes the behavior.

To decide which to use, think about your end-user and what would be easier for them when authoring the page.

To add an opinion, I would probably go with option 1. Sure it's not the most DRY approach. But it would give a content author a much clearer way of seeing what to do vs adding a style tick option. Especially if you make sure that the Rendering Variants have thumbnails so the authors get an idea of what they look like.

Comment: found this , it might be helpful https://www.maartenwillebrands.nl/2021/02/23/sitecore-sxa-scriban-includes/